# sed replace end of line with text and quote

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to change a line of type

```
DIRLIST="DIR/1 DIR/2 DIR/3"
```

to include a new DIR/4, using a bash script, where the DIR/4 is a command line argument

at the moment, this is my code for the replacing

```
sed "#DIRLIST#s#$# $logFolder\"#g" compress_log.sh > tmpCompress
```

this should replace $ with the contents of logFolder on every line containing DIRLIST, and redirect it to tmpCompress, shouldn't it?

The trouble i'm facing is I think due to slashes and quotes and the likes.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line below will work. It

- Searches for all lines that have DIRLIST
- Changes the " at the end of the line to....
- "$logFolder" followed by ...
- The " character

  `sed '/DIRLIST/ s:"$:'"$logFolder"'":'`

but it might be easier to understand if I split it up into pieces

```
sed '/DIRLIST/ s:"$:'            "$logFolder"             '":'
```

Please remember that you do can use two types of quotes on one line, and that the purpose of the quotes is to prevent the interpretation of special characters. The first part I use single quotes because I want to quote both a double quote, and a dollar sign. The second part I enclose in double quotes so the $ is interpreted as a variable, and in case there is a special character in the variable's value (as long as it does not include a colon). The third part I use single quotes to enclose a double quote and a colon (the last colon in the `s:old:new:` pattern) .

I prefer to use '..' instead of "..." in sed scripts by habit. It's safer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if `#DIRLIST#` should match a pattern, `/DIRLIST/` will do though.

```
$ export logFolder=NEWDIR
$ echo 'DIRLIST="DIR/1 DIR/2 DIR/3"' | sed "/DIRLIST/ s#\"\$# $logFolder\"#g"
DIRLIST="DIR/1 DIR/2 DIR/3 NEWDIR"
```

Comment: this one does work, but i didn't think you can add multiple answers, so thanks in any case, but i'm going to accept Bruces answer, due too the extra information.

Answer (score 1):

This command will do it:

```
sed -e "#DIRLIST# s#\"\$# $logFolder\"#g" compress_log.sh > tmpCompress
```

The reason your version fails is that "$#" is substituted with the number of positional arguments which for interactive shells is zero.

As a result `sed` executes this script instead:

```
#DIRLIST#s#0 <value of logFolder>"#g
```

You could have seen that if you prepended your command with echo, like this:

```
echo sed "#DIRLIST#s#$# $logFolder\"#g" compress_log.sh
```

To avoid that escape "$" with a backslash.

Next, as you need to add the new folder *inside* the quotes, you need to match and replace the last quote as well.

Additionally, the "g" flag is unnecessary as there is only one "end of string" matched by "$" in every line, so it cannot match more than once.

Comment: This doesn't work on my system. You need to change `#DIRLIST#` to `/DIRLIST/`

Answer (score 1):

The following works as well

```
old_folder='DIR[/]1 DIR[/]2 DIR[/]3'
sed "/""${old_folder}""/"' s#$# '"$logFolder"'#'
```

Comment: yes, but that would require knowing what folders I already included, whereas my solution has to work for unknown folders as well